# Transaction manager for service method that carries out DB operations on tables from multiple schemas

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

- The application is in Spring + hibernate.
- It has a process under which mysql tables from 3 schemas get updated.
- I have different dataSources, sessionFactories and
  transactionManagers for each schema.
- I have 3 DAO classes carrying out DB operations on their respective
  schema tables.
- Since all the DB operations are supposed to be under one single
  transaction, I am calling those dao methods from one service method.

But the problem is that I don't know how to annotate this service method `@Transactional`. Transactional annotation accepts only one transaction manager, but I am having 3.
Is my approach wrong? How can I solve this?

Comment: Why do you need to do the operation under one single transaction ?

Comment: @T.Des It's a customer registration process. And lot many tables need to be updated after every successful registration. To make sure all tables are updated, I need all of those operations under single transaction. If one fails, all others should roll back.

Comment: @Jeevan: Please check my improved answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to coordinate multiple transactional resources, then I think your only option is using distributed transaction management with JTA.
[This article](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/) explains how you can configure Spring to use a JTA transaction manager.

#### Edit:

After doing some research, it seems that you have a much better option if your three datasources really just point to different schemas (which are the same thing as databases in mysql) hosted by the same server. If that is the case, and you have a single user which is used for all your three connections, then you can basically merge them into one single connection, and use `@Table` annotations on your entities to specify the schema they belong to, like: `@Table(schema = "schemaX")`.

This can be done because the database name given in the connection URL only specifies the default database (see [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html#idp121944656)), but you can still execute SQL statements that qualify table names with other database names, which is exactly what the `@Table` annotation causes to Hibernate.

Having now one single connection resolves your original problem of doing atomic updates in tables from different schemas.

Comment: OK. I already have @Table annotations specified on my entity classes. Will try using single datasource and transaction. If it does the job then no need to created different transactions. Will let you know.

Comment: zagyi. I tried it, but it's not working. An exception is thrown saying  bean is not mapped. If I use 3 diff sessionFactories, Exception is not thrown.

Comment: You most likely get that exception, because you forgot to amend the configuration of the single SessionFactory. It needs to know all your entities in all three schemas, of course. If these entities are defined in different packages, you need to make sure that the SessionFactory's configuration covers all of them. Update your question with details about the config, if you still have problems with it.

Comment: You're right zagyi. I used same session factory but I missed specifying the other bean packages. I accept your answer. Thanks a lot :)